# Knockout enable javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am  trying to understand knockout. And there is a thing I don't understand. We have html:

```
<p>
<input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: hasCellphone" />
I have a cellphone</p>

<p>
Your cellphone number:
<input type='text' name='cell' data-bind="value: cellphoneNumber, enable: hasCellphone" /></p>

<button data-bind="enable: document.getElementsByName("cell")[0].value != '555'">
Do something</button>
```

And JS:

```
function AppViewModel() {   
this.hasCellphone = ko.observable(false);
this.cellphoneNumber = ko.observable("");}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

So, enable for input works, but not for the button, even if I enter '555' into the input it still stays enabled.

Comment: What's your parseAreaCode method? Is it definitely returning the correct value?

Comment: Sorry, wrong code here, I've just copied it from here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html, I'll edit is as I tried to use it.

Comment: Oh! Post your code then, as what you've posted should work, as long as you implement parseAreaCode correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example on the knockout page is a bit misleading. The enable binding takes *any* value but for automatic updates it must be an observable. `document.getElementsByName("cell")[0].value != '555'` is not an observable.

You can fix the code easily by adding a `cellphoneNumberValid` observable to the model which is based on the value of the `cellphoneNumber` observable:

### html

```
<p>
    <input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: hasCellphone" />
    I have a cellphone
</p>

<p>
    Your cellphone number:
    <input type='text' name='cell' data-bind="
            value: cellphoneNumber,
            valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
            enable: hasCellphone" />
</p>
```

Do something

### js

```
function parseAreaCode(s) {
    // just a dummy implementation
    return s.substr(0, 3);
}

function AppViewModel() {   
    this.hasCellphone = ko.observable(false);
    this.cellphoneNumber = ko.observable("");
    this.cellphoneNumberValid = ko.computed(function() {
        return parseAreaCode(this.cellphoneNumber()) != '555';
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/eL26h/

Comment: Created a fiddle to show that http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/x5Jx3/ (but this answer was faster :-)

Comment: wanted to to do that by myself, but you were waaaaaay faster :) thank you veeery much. answer above not working though

Comment: I just added a dummy parseAreaCode function and added the valueUpdate parameter. This is a common "error" and gives the impression that it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need the enable condition to be an observable, otherwise knockout doesn't check to see if the value has changed. You've just got it bound to an html element, which won't notify knockout when its value has changed. What happens if you try:

```
<button data-bind="enable: cellphoneNumber() != '555'">Do something</button>
```

Comment: Then you need a computed observable like bikeshedder has provided. :)

Comment: This solution also works but requires you to unfocus the phone number input field. If you want to update the cellphoneNumber observable on every keypress you can use the valueUpdate parameter: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to make this right, especially if you don't want to change your model. Big thanks to [bikeshedder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994342/bikeshedder) for his answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/NickBunich/C5vfV/2/

```
<p><input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: hasCellphone" />
I have a cellphone</p>
<p>Your cellphone number:
<input type='text' data-bind="value: cellphoneNumber, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enable: hasCellphone" /></p>
<button data-bind="enable: cellphoneNumber().trim().substr(0,3) !='555'">Do something</button>

function AppViewModel() {   
this.hasCellphone = ko.observable(false);
this.cellphoneNumber = ko.observable("");}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```